# Removing rows from even number columns if certain value is present

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array with the shape

```
(500,12)
```

All I want to do is to check whether the even number columns has a positive value, eg. `value > 0`. In that case I want to remove the whole row in my array. 
I put this up:

```
a = a[a[:,1] < 0, :]
```

This eliminates the desired rows but looks at the second column. I want it to check for column 4, column 6, column 8 etc too.

Is there an way of doing that using my method above?

Comment: Shouldn't the check be `<=`?

Comment: Not clear to me what you define to be the columns and what the rows. You say "In that case i want to remove the whole row in my array", you mean the whole column? You might consider using pandas.

Comment: My main array has 500 rows and 12 columns. I then want to check for each even column if it contains a positive value. If it does, the row should be eliminated from my main array, which then becomes 499 rows with 12 columns instead.

Comment: Yes numpy arrays. Im not sure what you're missing of information

Comment: Ah we are talking about numpy arrays. - your verbal description of the problem is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with NumPy arrays, then you could use [fancy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#fancy-indexing-and-index-tricks) approach (indexing an array with an array sequence of integers) as shown:

```
mask = (a[:, np.arange(1, a.shape[1], 2)] < 0).all(axis=1)
out = a[mask]
```

---

***Explanation:***

To select positions of odd numbered columns whose values are to be compared:

```
np.arange(1, a.shape[1], 2)         # a.shape[1] gives the number of columns
# array([ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11])
```

Next we subset the array based on these indices and see if the values under these columns are lesser than zero by providing `axis=1` which performs column-wise check and returns an array containing a reduced number of rows after dropping the remaining ones.

Answer (score 1):

Although perhaps not the most efficient way, you can use the *elementwise and* `&` for all the rows:

```
a = a[(a[:,1]<0)&(a[:,3]<0)&(a[:,5]<0)&(a[:,7]<0)&(a[:,9]<0)&(a[:,11]<0),:]
```

So you mask out all items for which there exists an even column that is positive.

You can make it more elegantly (with a minor performance penalty) by using [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools.reduce#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

a = a[reduce(lambda x,y:x&y,(a[:,i]<0 for i in range(1,12,2))),:]
```

In case the `shape` is not fully known in advance, you can use `.shape[1]`:

```
from functools import reduce

a = a[reduce(lambda x,y:x&y,(a[:,i]<0 for i in range(1,a.shape[1],2))),:]
```

Comment: I could but the thing is i would have a much larger number of columns. So im seeking for a general solution. I actually put this up, it looks like it works: 
for i in range (1, 12, 2):    
    a = a[a[:,i] < 0, :] 
Can you see any problems with this?

Comment: @MatiMalik: I think the edit crossed you comment. Semantically it is equivalent. But my guess is that you will pay a higher perforamance penalty since you filter the array each time in you approach.

Comment: Your updated solution is probably more simplified, thanks! Also do you have a suggestion to how to now convert all the negative values to positive in the even columns?

Comment: Works, awesome! The last thing i need to do now is to add the minimum absolute value of each ODD column to its respective column. This is a bit more tricky, i figured out how to do it individually a[:,0::2][:,0]+abs(min(a[:,0::2][:,0])) for the first row, but can't really put it in a loop for all the ODD columns

Comment: @MatiMalik: Does this help - `a[:,0::2] += np.abs(a[:,0::2].min())`.

Comment: @NickilMaveli Im not sure. The very first value should be exactly 0 but it gives something close to zero such as 7.76000000e-02. For example the minimum value in my first odd column is -12.6313 (+ 12.6313) should give 0. But perhaps your solution takes fewer decimals? ex. -12.6313 +12.63

Comment: I extracted the absolute minimum values from each ODD column in an numpy array as following: b=np.zeros(6)

for i in range (int(a.shape[1]/2)):

    b[i]=abs(min(a[:,0::2][:,i]))

The only thing now is to add each of this values to their whole respective column.

Answer (score 1):

The general way is to build a list comprehension with a condition:

```
a = [row for row in a if all(row[j] <= 0 for j in range(0, len(row), 2))]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a loop (as it iteratively shrinks your dataframe with some associated overhead):

```
m = (arr > 0) # check if positive; this is what you want to keep
m = arr.ix[:,1::2] # select only the even columns
m = arr.any(axis=1) # and check if any of them is true
```

So in one line:

```
 arr[(arr > 0)[:,1::2].all(axis=1),:]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `all` instead of `any`?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but the comments seem to suggest that. Changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Without using a loop, there is no single command that will help you with your motive. I suggest looping over all the rows and then doing this.